# Bouncing ray inside a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose I have a square with sides $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Now I shoot a ray from the vertex of the square formed by the sides, let's say $a$ and $b$ at angle $50^{\circ}$ from $a$. If I let the ray bounce off the sides of the square continuously, how many times would the ray intersect itself through exactly the same point in the square? Could you generalise this result to any angle $\alpha$?

Comment: If you shoot the ray in the way you described, it will reach a vetrex after the first reflection

Comment: You're right. I've changed the angle to 50∘ . By the way, what happens when it hits the corner as in the case of 60∘?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry I can't see any idea of your question, why choosing that angle not another one ?, There might be no general solution for your question and any special case will be of limited use

Comment: I've tried 45∘ which essentialy hits the other vertex on the diagonal of the square. And now as pointed out 60∘ hits the corner after one reflection.

Comment: The angle in itself is not very important. I could just choose any other one. I'm just interested in the behaviour of the intersections of these deflections as I vary the initial angle from the vertex. I recognize there might not be a general solution but I just wanted to see what other mathematicians could come up with and possible suggestions.

Comment: I don't really understand what's being asked. So we fix a point and want to see how many times a ray intersects itself? In any case, the ray has only two possible "slopes", so you'll only ever see two rays intersecting each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this figure, think about the symmetry of reflections at each wall:

[image]

You will get termination whenever $\theta = \tan^{-1} a/b$ where $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the number of reflections is $a+b$.

Conversely, you will never get termination if the $\theta = \tan^{-1} c$ where $c \notin \mathbb{Q}$, and thus the ray will intersect itself an infinite number of times.

Comment: Just an aside: In the case where the ray where intersects itself an infinite number of times, is it ever possible to have an intersection of at least 3 lines through some common point P in the square?

Comment: @JCr No — consider the angles of the lines themselves. Since each reflection flips one of the coordinates of the direction of the line, there are only two different possible slopes; the odd-reflected one and the even-reflected one. So any intersection must be between two segments of these two different slopes, and there's no 'third angle' a line could come in from.

Comment: That's brilliant. I'd like to thank you and also David G. Stork for these very helpful anwers. I have now a much better picture of this problem.